# replace wordpress login with my custom web application login

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am developing a web application in which users can signup, login and social login. I need a blog too in the same application. I choose wordpress.

But the problem is if user already have account on my application, he/she can login with the same credentials on wordpress with same session management.

Is it possible and how to replace Wordpress login?

Comment: SO is more about 'what is wrong with my code' than 'how would I go about solving...'

Answer (score 1):

You can do the stuff in the following way:

Keep wordpress folder name blog/ in your project root dirtectory.
And then create wordpress user with same credentials such as your application.
Put the below code in your application when you create new login user:

```
require_once('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
require_once('blog/wp-includes/registration.php');
$newusername = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$newpassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$newemail = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.co.in';
// Check that user doesn't already exist
if ( !username_exists($newusername) && !email_exists($newemail) ){
   // Create user and set role to administrator
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $newusername, $newpassword, $newemail);
   if ( is_int($user_id) )      {
       $wp_user_object = new WP_User($user_id);
       $wp_user_object->set_role('contributor');
            echo 'Successfully created new user.';
    } else {
            echo 'No users were created.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'This user or email already exists. Nothing was done.';
}
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood you right...
But you wrote: he/she CAN login with the same credentials on wordpress with same session management.

Sure you didn't meen can't ? Otherwise i don't see your problem...

But if you meant CAN'T... so, i don't know how wordpress is nowaday, but i tried the same thing maybe three years ago... it endet up that i coded my own blog, took me much less time than handle with all this wordpressstuff. And btw, writing your own blog application is really easy... There are 100 of tutorials and if you want i can help you, shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: I want only one login credential for one user on both my application and wordpress blog. I know creating custom blog is easy, But I don't want to reinvent the wheel when wordpress is already a popular blog platform

Comment: I don't think that writing your own blog is reinventing the wheel... Wordpress is a really powerful blog system, but in my opinion its just way too big for most of application using it. You don't have to buy a ferrari if you just want to drive a bit from a to b. (I know wordpress is for free..)

But back to your problem. I don't know if there is any easy way to do it, but as i said, i think you will be much faster when you just write your own blog. Wordpress has tousands of lines of code, its not a fast action implemention your own stuff if you don't know how wordpress is built.